# Windows batch script should run at some interval

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to implement timer in batch script for windows i.e. the code snippet given below is a simple loop but I want this loop should execute at certain time interval.(as for example i want it to run 100 times at the interval of 6 sec)

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 100) do (
   echo %x
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put ping command inside your for loop.

**ping -n 1 -i 5** 1.2.3.4

here,

n = number of iteration
i = number of second (Time to Live), and 1.2.3.4 is some invalid ip which is not pingable

in my example, i am waiting for 5 Sec.